# Native cl.exe on Windows 7 64-bit Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cl

What editon of Visual Studio 2013 do I need to have a native 64-bit `cl.exe`(`amd64` one, not `x86_amd64`)? I am running Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2013 Express (Windows Desktop Development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Visual C++ Express the x64 native compiler is not provided. You need at least the "Professional" edition.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9(v=vs.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Anyhow, you can build 64 bit executables just fine using the x86-x64 cross compiler running on WOW64.